# Python(17874,0x111e92dc0) malloc: can't allocate region

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I am building a Python web scraping script and i have to use cv2 (OpenCV). So I install using `pip install opencv-python` as the website directs. And it also installs numpy as a dependency.

However, right after installing that, I'm unable to run my python script. It crashes with the error below:
[image]

I think the issue is from Numpy but I don't know how to fix this. Please help.

This is my environment:

- MacOS 10.15.7
- Python 3.9.0
- pip 20.2.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
- Numpy 1.19.2
- opencv-python  4.4.0.44

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue when I tried to run a project I made on Windows on Mac OS. The solution I found was to install an older version of numpy (e.g. numpy 1.18).

Here is the command I ran to do so :

```
sudo python -m pip install numpy==1.18 --force
```

I don't think it is a good solution but it is ok for a temporary fix.

Comment: Alright @CDulouard, I will try this and give you feedback shortly

Comment: I did just as you mentioned and I did not get that annoying error again. Thanks a lot